# Why am I seeing the Apache2 default screen for CentOS even if I am running ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, centos

I have two apache virtual hosts (domain based) installed on a server running ubuntu (82.223.117.149).
It's `uname -a` is `Linux localhost 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The first VHost (running wordpress) has the base domain name assigned (eg: example.com and www.example.com) while the second one (running a moodle installation) has a subdomain assigned (campus.example.com).

The weird thing is that, when I access the subdomain (campus.example.com) I get the apache2 default page (even if vhosts are correctly configured and were working fine just a few days ago) for CentOS (as I said, my server runs ubuntu).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: May we have a look at your configuration file?

Comment: does nslookup campus.example.com resolve the right ip? You can check the apache log (by default it's located in /var/log/apache2/access.log) as well to try to see what is wrong.